# Lucee S3 NullPointerException with no further error info

Tags: java, amazon-s3, nullpointerexception, coldfusion, lucee

We are using Lucee and S3 and in our development and testing we had no problems.  We have now moved this code live and are getting a  lot of errors.That look like this :

[image: Screenshot of Error]

In the application.cfc  in OnError I have a chuck of code that will usually send me an email with some detail

```
<tr><td>Error message</td><td>#Exception.message#</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
  <td>Context</td>
  <td>
     <cftry>
        line : #Exception.TagContext[1].line#<br><br>
        template : #Exception.TagContext[1].template#<br><br>
        error : #Exception.TagContext[1].codePrintHTML#<br>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            have to figure it out yourself<br>
        </cfcatch>
     </cftry>
   </td>
</tr>
```

But it is sending this

[image: Emailed Error]

I am using this:

```
savecontent variable="logEntry"{
  writeOutput(chr(13)&chr(10)& serializeJSON(arguments.Exception) &chr(13)&chr(10))
  writeOutput('---------------------------'&chr(13)&chr(10))
}


writeLog(type="Error"
         ,  text=logEntry
         ,  file="SystemErrors");
```

to try and write to a log file. but even that is geving me no information. Log contains :

     `"ERROR","ajp-nio-8009-exec-8","09/12/2018","13:33:15","","
 {""Extended_Info"":"""",""Message"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""Cause"":{""Extended_Info"":"""",""Message"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""Detail"":"""",""additional"":{},""TagContext"":[],""ErrorCode"":""0"",""type"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""StackTrace"":""lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n"",""ExtendedInfo"":""""},""Detail"":"""",""additional"":{},""TagContext"":[],""ErrorCode"":""0"",""name"":""onRequest"",""type"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""StackTrace"":""lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n"",""rootCause"":{""Extended_Info"":"""",""Message"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""Detail"":"""",""additional"":{},""TagContext"":[],""ErrorCode"":""0"",""type"":""java.lang.NullPointerException"",""StackTrace"":""lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n"",""ExtendedInfo"":""""},""ExtendedInfo"":""""}`

After doing a LOT of googling about the NullPointerException error, all I can find out is that it seems to be a kind of "catch all" error.

At this point I can't prove that it is related to the S3 interaction/communication (because I can't even get a line number for where the error is occurring) I feel pretty sure it is related.

I had someone send me this error :

[image: Error from user on ImageRead]

And someone else report they got an error about cfdirectory which would have had to have been :

```
    if(!directoryExists(arguments.dirName)){
        directoryCreate(arguments.dirName);
        // cfdirectory(action="create", directory="#arguments.dirName#", mode="775");
    }
```

I am hoping that someone else has used Lucee's S3 functionality and has had similar results and can point me in the right direction.

As Suggested by Ageax I add an in email in a catch but get no more information.

[image]

Comment: Last time I had a NullPointerException without any info, it was related to a HTTP request to a 3rd party service that occasionally dropped the connection.

Comment: How does one go about testing and fixing that? This sounds like what may be happening but if I am getting no feedback at all not sure how to even test

Comment: "a chuck of code that will usually send me an email "  FWIW, the code in the try/catch would error if there was no TagContext. It may not provide any additional information whatsoever, but ... wouldn't hurt to try cfdump'ing the #Exception# object inside the catch clause.

Comment: "add an in email in a catch" It's dumping the *original* error #Exception#, not #cfcatch# - correct?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that is the #catch#

Comment: Well you want the original error, not the one from the try/catch. Add a dump of #Exception# to see if there's any more info in the original object.

Comment: Upgraded S3 Resource extension from 0.9.04.117 snapshot (or something similar) to 0.9.4.117 in the Lucee Admin which had a very positive effect.